# Phonegap - How to get rid of Uncaught Type Errors

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, cordova

I had developed Android Phonegap Application(**Phonegap Versio 1.4.1**) having one `HTML` file with multiple div tags(Each `<div>` is a single UI page) and `<script>` tag having Javascript methods. The application works fine and not getting any errors. Now, the requirement is each `<div>` in the HTML page to be divided as single `HTML` page and the Javascript, what i have developed is separated and placed as `jscript.js` file. So, now there are multiple `HTML` Pages and an external Javascript file and the `HTML` files will access `jscript.js` file. Now, the application returns some errors in the Logcat as below:

```
Web Console(19120): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clear' of undefined.
Web Console(19120): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined.
```

The above errors are displaying at Phonegap methods "`window.plugins.statusBarNotification.clear`" and  "`navigator.notification.alert`".

How to get rid of these errors? Due to these things, the application is not working as expected. Googled a lot of time, but cant find the solution. Anyone, experienced the same? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Have you added the cordova notification plugin? (take a look at app/res/xml/plugins.xml) Are you calling the function before deviceReady event has occured? That would not be allowed.

Comment: @Vic yes, added and calling before onDeviceReady event. I want to to know why these type of errors are occuring many times?

Comment: You can't call the methods before you get deviceready. Also, I have never heard of "clear" in any of our API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever plugins you are using, you should use it after the device is ready to avoid such errors.